# F# type extension with units of measure type conversion resulting in strange error

Tags: f#, units-of-measurement, type-extension

I have a function that converts from my own implementation of a 3D vector (which supports units of measure) to XNA's implementation:

```
type Vector3<[<Measure>]'a> with
    member inline v.ToXna() =
        Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector3(v.x / 1.f<_>, v.y / 1.f<_>, v.z / 1.f<_>)
```

When I compile it, I get a strange error:

> The signature and implementation are not compatible because the type
>   parameter in the class/signature has a different compile-time
>   requirement to the one in the member/implementation

The `inline` seems to be a necessity; without it, I get this error:

> This construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by the
>   type annotations. The unit-of-measure variable 'a has been constrained
>   to be measure 'm'.

Any idea what's going on?

**Edit** To answer @svick's questions, Vector3 is defined as:

```
type Vector3<[<Measure>]'u> =
    struct
        val x:float32<'u>
        val y:float32<'u>
        val z:float32<'u>
        new(x, y, z) = { x = x; y = y; z = z }
    end
```

And I'm also having some type inference problems defining it as a normal function:

```
let vector3 (v:DumpEngine.Vector3<_>) =
    Vector3(v.x / 1.f<_>, v.y / 1.f<_>, v.z / 1.f<_>)
```

Causes the function to be a Vector3<1> -> Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector3, which makes it quite unusable. I'm not sure this is a related issue, though.

Comment: Does it work if you don't write it as a type extension? How is `Vector3` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what's going on, but this seems to work:

```
let inline ToXna(v:Vector3<'a>) =
    Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector3(v.x / 1.f<_>, v.y / 1.f<_>, v.z / 1.f<_>)
```

It's the best I managed to do, though.

Answer (score 6):

Another solution, which circumvents the problem entirely by using a cast rather than a divison:

```
type Vector3<[<Measure>]'u> with
    member inline v.ToXna() =
        Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector3(float32 v.x, float32 v.y, float32 v.z)
```

Comment: I think this *is* the canonical way to 'ununit' things. (Just for reference for future visitors, the opposite can be achieved with [FloatWithMeasure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806527.aspx).)